# Multiple Functions for Single Event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have one function for one element:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dothis()">Link</a>
```

When this function is done, how can I run another function after this one?

For example, if this function returns true, then the script will run another function and if not, it will not run the second function.

Or have the second function run without regard to the result of the first function.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Just call the function after that function. If you are already using jQuery, I recommend to use it also for binding the event handler.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Like, can't the last of `dothis()` be `dothat();`?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+onclick+call+two+functions

Comment: wait, you're not even using jQuery at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="if (dothis() == true) dothat();">Clicky</a>
```

Comment: Better: `if (dothis()) dothat();`.

Comment: This is what I could use thanks :) It's easy to add another function inside original one, but I had something else in mind

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, true, but unlike PHP, JS always confuses me as to what it considers a "true" statement... I sometimes can't check for a null without it breaking!

Comment: Yeah, this can be confusing. But if we assume that the function returns `true` then there is really no reason to compare it to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call another function from `dothis()`

```
 function dothis(){

  // Do something

    if(val == true)
    {
     // Call another function
      anotherFunction();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `onclick` attribute, you can use normal javascript, socalled inline javascript.
So you could do (disencouraged):

```
<a onclick="if(dothis()) dothat()" />
```

You could do (recommended):

```
<a onclick="dothisandthat()" />

<script>
    function dothisandthat() {
        if (dothis())
            dothat();
</script>
```

Comment: Why is that not recommended? Maybe he wants to only use the second function in one specific link while all others do not share the same logic. Naturally he /could/ use a parameter (maybe a boolean) to determine which function call would trigger the second one, but seeins as this is unneeded and takes more space, is that really necessary?

Comment: Inline javascript should always be kept short. @OhMrBigshot

Comment: One function is still readable, but putting an if-statement in there doesn't help. Things get interesting when adding an else-clause.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a real problem, I thinkan if and else is ok. I've seen IP.Board do worse!

Comment: That could be server generated. You don't know how that looks like in PHP. that could be something like: `<el onclick="<? echo $scriptToDoSomething ?>" />`. That stays readable, and the scripts can even be in an included (or required) PHP file.

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way:

```
doThis() && doThat();
```

jQuery:

```
$('#el').click(function() {
    doThis() && doThat();
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript://" onclick="doThis() && doThat();">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

call the other function at end of `dothis`

If you want to use `dothis` with other elements. simply use a callback function.

```
function dothis(callback) {

 // code

 callback();

}
```

then use it like this:

```
dothis(dothisafter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call that another function at the end of `dothis` function like this

```
function dothis(){

  if(someThing == true)
    someFunc();
}
```